# sort and display names on different lines in ascending order

Tags: javascript, sorting

My professor wants us to Write a JavaScript code that prompts the user to enter 3 names (one at a time). The program should
sort and display the names on different lines in ascending order.

This is what I have so far

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Day 2 - Example 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
 <script language="javascript">
   var na1,na2,na3;
   na1=prompt("Enter your first name:","");
   na2=prompt("Enter your second name:","");
   na3=prompt("Enter your third name","");  
 </script>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet. They are unrelated. Also, [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2):

I think your professor wants you learn something in the process, so I try to explain you how to attack the problem. Please feel free to ask any follow up question you have.

So, you have you three names, in three different variables.

You have two main problems: **compare** the names, and **sort** them by the result of the comparison.

Let's take one step at time.

What does **to compare** two names mean? Or, in another worlds, what does it means that one name is before another?

Let's suppose, for simplicity, that the inserted names contains only chars from *a* to *z*, both in lower or upper case. There are no numbers, no special chars (like *è*) or anything else (you can try eventually to expand the code to take care of other characters too).

So, to **compare** the two names we create a function which takes two names as arguments and returns `-1` as result if the first name comes before the second, `0` if they are equal, and `1` otherwise.

The function will be something like this:

```
function compare(name1, name2) {
    // Do same magic stuff
    return -1;
}
```

First of all, we can compare the first letter of the names, and check which one comes first.
The best way to take a char out of a string is using the [charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) function. You can also access a string as an array, but it doesn't work on IE7, and from an academic point of view is wrong.

But in real world, writing `name[1]` is the same of writing `name.charAt(1)`

```
function compare(name1, name2) {
    if (name1.charAt(0) < name2.charAt(0)) return -1;
    if (name1.charAt(0) === name2.charAt(0)) return 0;
    if (name1.charAt(0) > name2.charAt(0)) return 1; 
}
```

Uhm, it is a beginning, but this code has a lot of problems.

The second `if` will make the function returning 0 if the first letter of the two names is the same. This doesn't make any sense.

We know that two names are equal if and only if they are all equals.
We can then change the check to make sure all the chars in the two names are the same:

```
function compare(name1, name2) {
    if (name1 === name2) return 0;

    if (name1.charAt(0) < name2.charAt(0)) return -1;
    if (name1.charAt(0) > name2.charAt(0)) return 1; 
}
```

Definitely better.

But another problem we have with this code is that if someone inserted her name with a capital letter, she will be always before someone who inserted the name using only lower case letters.

So `alice` will come after `Bob` in our case.

We need to compare the same character, so we will compare only lower case chars. To transform our names in all lower case letters, we use the [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) function

```
function compare(name1, name2) {
    name1 = name1.toLowerCase();
    name2 = name2.toLowerCase();

    if (name1 === name2) return 0;

    if (name1.charAt(0) < name2.charAt(0)) return -1;
    if (name1.charAt(0) > name2.charAt(0)) return 1; 
}
```

Okay!

But what if the first chars of the two names is the same?

Mhh, we didn't think about it! We have to check for every char as long we do not find one different or one of the two names doesn't have any more char!

First of all, let's find the shortest name:

`var lengthOfShorterName = Math.min(name1.length, name2.length)`

[Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) will return the littlest number among the ones you pass as arguments. 
We can create now a `for`cycle to compare every char, one by one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfShorterName; i++) {
    if (name1.charAt(i) > name2.charAt(i)) return 1;
    if (name1.charAt(i) < name2.charAt(i)) return -1;
}
```

But what if one name is a sub-string of the other (that is, *Ali* and *Alice*)?

Well, the for cycle will finish, so we need another condition.
Let's say that the shorter name comes first.

```
if (name1.lenght < name2.length) return -1;
return 1;
```

We finally have our compare function :)

```
function compare(name1, name2) {
    name1 = name1.toLowerCase();
    name2 = name2.toLowerCase();

    if (name1 === name2) return 0;

    var lengthOfShorterName = Math.min(name1.length, name2.length)

    for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfShorterName; i++) {
        if (name1.charAt(i) > name2.charAt(i)) return 1;
        if (name1.charAt(i) < name2.charAt(i)) return -1;
    }

    if (name1.lenght < name2.length) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

Now we need to sort the elements.

Sorting is a very complex subjects, and there are a lot of different approaches, with a lot of pros and cons. But also an overall analysis would be too much for this answer, so let's do a little trick here: we know we have three names, so we can directly compare them thanks to our new function!

Let's first of all do all the comparison!

```
var na1_na2 = compare(na1, na2);
var na1_na3 = compare(na1, na3);
var na2_na3 = compare(na2, na3);

// We create the place where we will save the names
var first, second, third;

if (na1_na2 === -1) {
    // na1 comes before na2! Will it come also before na3?
    if (na1_na3 === -1) {
        // Yes! So na1 is the first!
        first = na1;

        // But who is second?
        if (na2_na3 === -1) {
            // na2 is second!
            second = na2;
            third = na3;
        } else {
            // na3 is second!
            second = na3;
            third = na2;
        }
    } else {
        // na3 is before na1, therefore is first!
        first = na3
        second = na1;
        third = na2;
    }
} else {
    // na2 is before na1. What do we need to compare?
}
```

Now, of course you will not use a solution like this in the real world.
First of all, because I left out a lot of corner cases (and also ignored when the function compare returns 0).

Second, and mainly, because you do not leverage the Javascript native functions.

The answer by @shash679 shows you a real world implementation of the solution.

But anyway, I hope you enjoyed the explanation and mainly you are curious now to find out more about Javascript and computer science in general.

Writing code is not about writing code, it is more about resolving riddles, and it's quite fun.

Good luck with your course!

Answer (score 1):

You could store the names entered by the user into an array and then use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
function nameSorting() {
    var names = [];
    var name1 = prompt("Please enter the first name");
    names[0] = name1;
    var name2 = prompt("Please enter the second name");
    names[1] = name2;
    var name3 = prompt("Please enter the second name");
    names[2] = name3;
    names.sort();
    
    document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = names[0];
    document.getElementById("secondName").innerHTML = names[1];
    document.getElementById("lastName").innerHTML = names[2];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to to enter 3 names (one at a time). The program will sort and display the names on different lines in ascending order.</p>

<button onclick="nameSorting()">Enter names</button>

<p id="firstName"></p>
<p id="secondName"></p>
<p id="lastName"></p>

</body>
</html>
```